# Marionette - throws error on `removeRegions` how to solve it

Tags: marionette

In my app, i have the regions as `header`,`content`,`footer` - in which on the login page, I don't want to use the `header`, and `footer`. for that, on `onRender` i remove the regions what i don't want to be.

But I am getting an error saying: `Cannot read property 'empty' of undefined`.

here is my template : (i use jade )

```
div#wrapper
        script(type='text/template', id="appTemplate")
            div#header
            div#content
            div#footer
        script(type='text/template', id="loginTemplate")
            div this is login template
```

here is my layout.js:

```
socialApp.AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
        el:'#wrapper',
        template:'#appTemplate',
        regions: {
            header : '#header',
            content : '#content',
            footer : '#footer'
        },

        onRender : function () {
            this.removeRegion("header", "#header"); //i am removing header alone here.
        }
    });
```

here is my controller.js

```
socialApp.loginController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
        _initialize:function(){
            this.loginView = new loginView({model:new loginModel});
            this.layout.onRender(); //calling onRender from here...
            this.layout.content.show(this.loginView);
        }
    });
```

But it's all not working. any one help me the correct way please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** call methods that are prefixed with `on` manually. Those are there for your code to react to given events, in this case that the view’s `render` method was invoked.

I would suggest that you instead of trying to remove and then later re-add regions, you create two different layouts. Then when your router hits the `login` route, you render `LoginLayout` into your App’s root region, and for other routes, the ‘normal’ layout. Here’s how I solved something similar:

**app.js:**

```
var App = new Marionette.Application;
App.addRegions({ root: '#acme' });

// Instantiate User model
App.addInitializer(function()
{
    this.user = new UserModel;
});

// Render App layout
App.addInitializer(function()
{
    this.layout = this.user.get('id') ? new ContentLayoutView({ identifier: 'content' }) : new UserLayoutView({ identifier: 'user' });
    this.root.show(this.layout);

    // And let the routers decide what goes in the content region of each layout
    this.router = {
        content: new ContentRouter,
        user: new UserRouter
    };
});
```

**layout/content.js**

```
var ContentLayout = Marionette.LayoutView.extend(
{
    identifier: 'content',
    template: ContentLayoutTemplate,

    regions: {
        content: '[data-region="content"]',
        panelLeft: '[data-region="panel-left"]',
        panelRight: '[data-region="panel-right"]'
    },

    initialize: function()
    {
        this.content.once('show', function(view)
        {
            this.panelLeft.show(new PanelLeftView);
            this.panelRight.show(new PanelRightView);
        }.bind(this));
    }
});
```

**layout/user.js**

```
var UserLayout = Marionette.LayoutView.extend(
{
    identifier: 'user',
    template: UserLayoutTemplate,

    regions: {
        content: '[data-region="content"]'
    }
});
```

**router/content.js**

```
var ContentRouter = Marionette.AppRouter.extend(
{
    routes: {
        '(/)': '...'
    },

    createLayout: function(callback)
    {
        if(App.root.currentView.options.identifier != 'content')
        {
            var layout = new ContentLayoutView({ identifier: 'content' });
            this.region = layout.content;
            this.listenTo(layout, 'show', callback);
            App.root.show(layout);
        }
        else
        {
            this.region = App.root.currentView.content;
            callback();
        }
    },

    execute: function(callback, args)
    {
        if(App.user.get('id'))
        {
            this.createLayout(function()
            {
                callback.apply(this, args);
            }.bind(this));
        }
        else
            App.router.user.navigate('login', true);
    }
});
```

**router/user.js**

```
var UserRouter = Marionette.AppRouter.extend(
{
    routes: {
        'login(/)': 'showLogin',
        'logout(/)': 'showLogout'
    },

    createLayout: function(callback)
    {
        if(App.root.currentView.options.identifier != 'user')
        {
            var layout = new UserLayoutView({ identifier: 'user' });
            this.region = layout.content;
            this.listenTo(layout, 'show', callback);
            App.root.show(layout);
        }
        else
        {
            this.region = App.root.currentView.content;
            callback();
        }
    },

    execute: function(callback, args)
    {
        this.createLayout(function()
        {
            callback.apply(this, args);
        }.bind(this));
    },

    showLogin: function()
    {
        var LoginView = require('view/detail/login');
        this.region.show(new LoginView);
    },

    showLogout: function()
    {
        var LogoutView = require('view/detail/logout');
        this.region.show(new LogoutView);
    }
});
```